# Configuration to Automatically De-dupe by Email in User Initiated Sends in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Is there a configuration that can be used so that the option for de-dupe by email is checked by default when building a User Initiated email send in SFMC?  Currently, this has to be manually checked each time.

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible - you could talk with SFMC Support to see if they have any options, but it is not possible (outside maybe building programmatically via API)  from a general user perspective.